# Can't install ecodmsserver on crunchbang++ / Debian 9 stretch

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

I tried to install "ecodms Server" on Linux according to the installation manual.

But I have several issues installing the software, which leads me to the assumption that I am missing in general some deb sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

When I try to install the software, I get the following info (in German):

```
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten: ecodmsserver : 
Hängt ab von: libqt5sql5 soll aber nicht installiert werden 
Hängt ab von: libqt5xml5 soll aber nicht installiert werden 
Hängt ab von: libqt5sql5-psql soll aber nicht installiert werden 
Hängt ab von: postgresql soll aber nicht installiert werden 
Hängt ab von: samba soll aber nicht installiert werden 
Hängt ab von: postgresql soll aber nicht installiert werden 
Hängt ab von: oracle-java8-unlimited-jce-policy ist aber nicht installierbar oder openjdk-8-jre soll aber nicht installiert werden 
Hängt ab von: libapr1 ist aber nicht installierbar haveged : 
Hängt ab von: libhavege1 (>= 1.9.0) ist aber nicht installierbar
```

I am on Debian 9 Stretch. It says depends on but should not be installed or depends on and is not installable. I tried to install them individually but with no success.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

`sources.list`:

```
#
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9 _Stretch_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170621-14:43]/ stretch contrib main non-free
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9 _Stretch_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170621-14:43]/ stretch contrib main non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://www.ecodms.de/ecodms_180964/stretch /
```

Comment: do you already have some oracle java 8 repository configured . Search by this, that is probably the answer.

Comment: deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9 _Stretch_ - Official Snapshot amd64
LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170621-14:43]/ stretch contrib main non-free

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9 _Stretch_ - Official Snapshot amd64 L
IVE/INSTALL Binary 20170621-14:43]/ stretch contrib main non-free

 deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://www.ecodms.de/ecodms_180964/stretch /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I could install haveget on my other system (SparkyLinux, also Debian based) and compared the sources list, I added following missing entries:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free 
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free
```

then I executed:

```
apt-get update
apt --fix-broken install
```

with those, the installation executed successfully.